# Pass lots of data from a single anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

What is the best way to pass a lot of data from a single link? Is something like this a good idea or is there a better way?

```
<a href="{ 'id':'1', 'foo':'bar', 'something':'else' }" id="myLnk" > Click </a>


$('#myLnk).click( function(event){
  event.preventDeafult();
  var data = $(this).attr('href')
  console.log( $.parseJSON( response ) );

})
```

Thanks!

Comment: To get the best answer possible, can you give us some more context? Explain more what happens around this code, how the data i rendered and what it is used for.

Comment: @Ancide, it's just a general question. I'm not really trying to do anything specific. Just wondering what best practice is.

Comment: Alright, why I'm wondering is just because in this case depending on what the context is there are different answers. Which works better depending on the context.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably to use [custom data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) in your anchor tag.

For example:

```
<a href="#" data-json="{ 'id':'1', 'foo':'bar', 'something':'else' }">Click</a>
```

You can then easily access this data from your JavaScript using the jQuery [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data) function.

Or, rather than bundling all the data together in a single JSON block, you can split it into separate attributes:

```
<a id="myLnk"
    data-id="1"
    data-foo="bar"
    data-something="else">
```

These can then be retrieved using jQuery like this:

```
$("#myLnk").data("id")
$("#myLnk").data("foo")
$("#myLnk").data("something")
```

Comment: Thanks Chris (and html5), this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Chris, see my note below for $.data()... I just found this out myself, actually.

Comment: is there a way to post the data to another page? or is this purely to view the data on the same page?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way is to use HTML5 `data-*` attributes:

```
<a href="#" id="myLnk" data-id="1" data-foo="bar" data-something="else">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Chris's & MvChr's responses, you can also do this, although I *hate* using single quotes for attributes:

```
<a href='#' data-json='{ "id":1, "foo":"bar", "something":"else" }'>Click</a>
```

The reason for this syntax is because if you quote it properly, $.data in jQuery will automatically work.  Otherwise, you have to $.parseJSON($.data(selector)) the information.